# JQuery slideshow, progressbar and events not unregistering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, slideshow

I'm having a hard time figuring out my problem.
It seems like the jquery off method is not working.

Here is what i am trying to do. I'm using a plugin called Slideshowify to create a slideshow with a ken burns effect and a jquery progress bar to show for how long each images will be shown on screen.

The problem is that the plugin doesn't handle the window resize. So what I am trying to achieve is to register to the window resize event and reset the plugin when the window is resized.

To start and restart my progress bar I'm using 2 events, one before the image is shown, one after it's being hidden. All works fine, but the problem is that the off method doesn't seem to unregister the events.

So if you resize the window multiple times, many events will be registered and fired and the progress bar will reset when it's not suppose to.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.slideshowify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startSlideShow()
        {
            $("body").off(); //unregister the events
            $("div[id^='slideshowify']").remove(); //remove the div that the plugin created
            $("#slideshow img").slideshowify();
            $("body").on("beforeFadeIn", onBeforeFadeIn); //event fired before an image is shown
            $("body").on("beforeFadeOut", onBeforeFadeOut); //event fired before an image is hidden
        }
        function onBeforeFadeIn(e, img)
        {
            startProgress();
        }
        function onBeforeFadeOut(e, img)
        {
            startProgress();
        }
        function startProgress()
        {
            $("#progressbar .ui-progressbar-value").stop(true, true); //stop the progress animation
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0.1 }); //create/reset the progress bar
            $("#progressbar .ui-progressbar-value").animate({ width: "100%" }, 9000); //start the progress animation
        }
        function onWindowResize()
        {
            startSlideShow();
            startProgress();
        }
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            startSlideShow();
            $(window).resize(onWindowResize); //event fired when the window is resized
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0001.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0002.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0003.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0004.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0006.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0012.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0014.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.narcissusphoto.com/weddings//mariage_20130810_0016.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="progressbar" style="height:20px; width:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you resize the window, jQuery is going to call the .resize() function many times in that one "resizing".

[Fiddle that console logs the resize events](http://jsfiddle.net/TpsM8/)

The .off() method is probably working but you're expecting that

```
$(window).resize(onWindowResize);
```

is only firing once when you are done resizing the window. That's not the case.  It seems that you need to use a timeout to achieve what you want.

[Using Timeout](http://www.jquery4u.com/events/jquery-capture-window-resize-event/)

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
    window.resizeEvt;
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);
        window.resizeEvt = setTimeout(function()
        {
            //code to do after window is resized
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seems to change anything. I've even put a console.log  when the window is resized and i can confirm that the resize is called  just once.

Comment: And by called once i meant when you just double click on the title bar  of the browser, the resize event is fired only once and the problem still happens.